# What is the best way of getting default value from Type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have Type and I want to get the default value. For example, if Type is class or nullable I should get null. But if it is integer, DateTime. decimal, ... I should get 0. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: maybe `default` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default

Comment: It depends on how you define your "best way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you can use something like this:

```
public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    return type.IsClass ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FIDL95314)

Answer (score 4):

From your description you can just use a [default expression or literal](http://default%20value%20expressions%20(C#%20reference)).

```
int a = default(int);
int a = default;
```

[Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

| Type | Default value |
| --- | --- |
| Any reference type | `null` |
| Anybuilt-in integral numeric type | `0` (zero) |
| Any built-in floating-point numeric type | `0` (zero) |
| bool | `false` |
| char | `'\0'` (U+0000) |
| enum | The value produced by the expression (E)0, where E is the enum identifier. |
| struct | The value produced by setting all value-type fields to their default values and all reference-type fields to null. |
| Any nullable value type | An instance for which the HasValue property is false and the Value property is undefined. That default value is also known as the null value of a nullable value type. |

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads) to generate an empty variable of the type and then check the value of it :)

Comment: A new instance of a reference type isn't the same as the default value though ([example](https://rextester.com/ZQUEG95191)). Using `Activator.CreateInstance` alone for reference types without parameterless constructors will also result in a `MissingMethodException` ([example](https://rextester.com/AEFH32408)).